# Discover if exception is thrown in finally part of try-finally block

Tags: java, try-finally

I have a simple question an simple part of code, some basic `try-finally` block:

```
try {
  // Some code which can throw an Exception
} finally {
  // Some code which also can throw an Exception
}
```

My main question would be: Is there any way we can discover is Exception thrown in `finally` block without using `catch` and some local variables to pass information between blocks?

I have few situations where this can be useful, and I don't want to add some ugly unnecessary `catch` blocks to just set some variable and `throw Exception` again. First example is that in case when I'm in some Spring or container managed transactional method, and in `try` block `Exception` occurred. I need to create new transaction in `finally` to work with database in that case. Second example is that I don't want to my original `Exception` be masked by `Exception` thrown in `finally` block, but if there was no `Exception` I will throw it from `finally` (if there was any).

I know it all can be done with `catch` but is there any other way, some metadata in Java or anything else? Also it can be helpful if we can assume that this will be executed in one `Thread`, so maybe there is some way to discover Exception bounded to current `Thread`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's something that has long frustrated me.

I normally declare a variable exceptionThrown=true at the top and set it to false just before returning. Then you can test that in the finally handler. I think that's better than catching and re-throwing because the latter approach will mess up the stack trace.

I'm surprised neither Java nor C# has a better way of handling this

Comment: Yes this is definitely better. And for now I don't see any other reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 7 then maybe [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) can help you.

It can handle closing the transaction so you won't need a `finally` block. Then you can put exception handling code (such as creating a new transaction) in a `catch` block. Finally, if exceptions are thrown from the `try` block and an exception is also thrown when releasing resources, the `try` exceptions will be available by calling `Throwable.getSuppressed` on the exception that was thrown when you closed the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature where possible:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Java 7 also enhanced Throwable with "suppressed exceptions":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions